# CXF JibX databinding Using the Binding Compiler

Tags: java, cxf, jibx

Anyone had luck using JibX databinding in CXF? I see that we need to run binding compiler. But, I'm not able to find out a way of doing this when using Jibx data binding in CXF.

Answer (score 0):

Gopal,
Absolutely! JiBX works great with CXF.
Take a look at these examples. Here is a simple [JiBX example](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/schema-library/webservices.html) that you can find in our repository.
If you a need step-by-step example, take a look at this [example from my blog](http://blog.tourgeek.com/2012/04/creating-soap-and-rest-services-for.html).
Hope this helps!
Don

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: **YES** - You can use Apache CXF with JiBX databinding.

I gave a litte explanation in this blog post:
[Using Apache CXF SOAP service with customized JiBX databinding](http://frvabe.blogspot.de/2013/04/using-apache-cxf-soap-service-with.html) and povided a simple example application [here](https://github.com/FrVaBe/cxf-soap-with-jibx#readme).